# Tesseract v4.0.0.20190314: SetVariable Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ocr, tesseract

trying to implement https://github.com/Neelarghya/tesseract-unity
so far tesseract doing nice job **but trying force it to only recognize: ".,0123456789"**

added:

```
[DllImport(TesseractDllName)]
private static extern bool SetVariable(IntPtr handle, string name, string value);
```

which is called inside:

```
public bool SetVariables(string _name, string _value)
{
    try
    {
        bool _result = SetVariable(m_tessHandle, _name, _value);
        if (!_result)
        {
            m_errorMsg = "SetVariables failed. Output: " + _result;
            Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        m_errorMsg = ex + " -- " + ex.Message;
        return false;
    }return true;
}
```

and above bool is called after Succeeful init call:

```
public void Setup()
{
    m_tesseract = new TesseractWrapper();
    string _datapath = Application.streamingAssetsPath
                   + "/tessdata/";

    if (m_tesseract.Init("eng", _datapath))
    {
        Debug.Log("Init Successful");
    }

    if (m_tesseract.SetVariables("tessedit_char_whitelist", ".,0123456789"))
    {
        Debug.Log("SetVaraibles Successful");
    }
}
```

currently public bool SetVariables resulting in false... any advice?

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { ... return false; }` - don't do that as it defeats the purpose of exception handling.  Checking return values is problematic.

Comment: so if remove all catching exceptions... an go with:

'public bool SetVariables(string _name, string _value)
    {
        return SetVariable(m_tessHandle, _name, _value);
    }'
will end with console error: "EntryPointNotFoundException: SetVariable"

Comment: _"EntryPointNotFoundException"_ - well there's your problem right there.  It can't find "SetVariable".  Did you spell it right?  Lucky we looked into this. :)

Comment: Thx @MickyD it's spelled right.... wondering is it possible that is not included in custom created TesseractDllName... in original version was not implemented, any tip for deep dive in 63Mb *.dll?

Comment: So as temporary solution, made separate trainfile for Tesseract... OCR was feed with graphic data collected from endused fonts, as a result Tesseract has greate succes ratio in reading digits (ofc with this font), still maybe someone will be able to support with main issue...

Comment: _"EntryPointNotFoundException"_ - is pretty self-explanatory.  There's something wrong with your DLL.  You need to fix that first.